# Redirect to previous filtered page after OnPost

Tags: c#, azure-sql-database, razor-pages

I have searched the entire day looking for a good answer. I am trying to redirect to a filtered page after I delete a record.

history.go(-1) works for a regular link (Back to List), but I cannot figure out to redirect back to a filtered page after I submit the deletion in OnPost.

Here is my index page where I perform the search and filter results:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.RazorPages;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
using WebApplication1.Models;

namespace WebApplication1.Pages.Assignments
{
    public class IndexModel : PageModel
    {
        private readonly WebApplication1.DBCtx _context;
        private readonly IConfiguration Configuration;

    public IndexModel(WebApplication1.DBCtx context, IConfiguration configuration)
    {
        _context = context;
        Configuration = configuration;
    }

    public string BrandSort { get; set; }
    public string AESort { get; set; }
    public string CustSort { get; set; }
    public string CurrentFilter { get; set; }
    public string CurrentSort { get; set; }
    public PaginatedList<Assignment> Pairing { get; set; }

    public async Task OnGetAsync(string sortOrder,
                                string currentFilter,
                                string searchString,
                                int? pageIndex)
    {
        CurrentSort = sortOrder;

        BrandSort = String.IsNullOrEmpty(sortOrder) ? "brand_desc" : "";
        AESort = String.IsNullOrEmpty(sortOrder) ? "name_desc" : "name_asc";
        CustSort = String.IsNullOrEmpty(sortOrder) ? "cust_desc" : "cust_asc";

        if (searchString != null)
        {
            pageIndex = 1;
        }
        else
        {
            searchString = currentFilter;
        }

        CurrentFilter = searchString;

        IQueryable<Assignment> assignmentsIQ = from s in _context.TblPairings
                                                .Include(a => a.Brand)
                                                .Include(b => b.People)
                                                .Include(c => c.Customer)
                                               select s;

        if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(searchString))
        {
            assignmentsIQ = assignmentsIQ.Where(s => s.Brand.Brand.Contains(searchString)
                                            || s.People.FirstName.Contains(searchString)
                                            || s.People.LastName.Contains(searchString)
                                            || s.Customer.CustomerAlias.Contains(searchString));
        }

        switch (sortOrder)
        {
            case "brand_desc":
                assignmentsIQ = assignmentsIQ.OrderByDescending(s => s.Brand.Brand);
                break;
            case "name_desc":
                assignmentsIQ = assignmentsIQ.OrderByDescending(s => s.People.LastName);
                break;
            case "name_asc":
                assignmentsIQ = assignmentsIQ.OrderBy(s => s.People.LastName);
                break;
            case "cust_desc":
                assignmentsIQ = assignmentsIQ.OrderByDescending(s => s.Customer.CustomerAlias);
                break;
            case "cust_asc":
                assignmentsIQ = assignmentsIQ.OrderBy(s => s.Customer.CustomerAlias);
                break;
            default:
                assignmentsIQ = assignmentsIQ.OrderBy(s => s.Brand.Brand)
                                                .ThenBy(s => s.Customer.CustomerAlias)
                                                .ThenBy(s => s.People.LastName);
                break;
        }

        var pageSize = Configuration.GetValue("PageSize", 50);
        Pairing = await PaginatedList<Assignment>.CreateAsync(assignmentsIQ.AsNoTracking(), pageIndex ?? 1, pageSize);

    }   
    }
}
```

And here is my delete page:

```
@page
@model WebApplication1.Pages.Assignments.DeleteModel

@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Delete Assignment";
}

<h1>Delete Assignment</h1>

<h3>Are you sure you want to delete this assignment?</h3>
<div>
    <hr />
    <dl class="row">
        <dt class="col-sm-2">
            Account Executive
        </dt>
        <dd class="col-sm-10">
            @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Assignment.People.FullName)
        </dd>
        <dt class="col-sm-2">
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Assignment.Brand)
        </dt>
        <dd class="col-sm-10">
            @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Assignment.Brand)
        </dd>
        <dt class="col-sm-2">
            Customer
        </dt>
        <dd class="col-sm-10">
            @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Assignment.Customer.CustomerAlias)
        </dd>
        <dt class="col-sm-2">
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Assignment.ActiveLine)
        </dt>
        <dd class="col-sm-10">
            @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Assignment.ActiveLine)
        </dd>
    </dl>
    
    <form method="post">
        <input type="hidden" asp-for="Assignment.RouteID" />
        <input type="submit" value="Delete" class="btn btn-danger" /> |
        <a class="btn btn-primary" OnClick="history.go(-1)">Back to List</a>
    </form>
</div>
```

And my delete model:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.RazorPages;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using WebApplication1;
using WebApplication1.Models;

namespace WebApplication1.Pages.Assignments
{
    public class DeleteModel : PageModel
    {
        private readonly WebApplication1.DBCtx _context;

        public DeleteModel(WebApplication1.DBCtx context)
        {
            _context = context;
        }

        [BindProperty]
        public Assignment Assignment { get; set; }

        public async Task<IActionResult> OnGetAsync(int? id)
        {
            if (id == null)
            {
                return NotFound();
            }

            Assignment = await _context.TblPairings
                .Include(a => a.Brand)
                .Include(b => b.People)
                .Include(c => c.Customer)
                .FirstOrDefaultAsync(m => m.RouteID == id);

            if (Assignment == null)
            {
                return NotFound();
            }
            return Page();
        }

        public async Task<IActionResult> OnPostAsync(int? id)
        {
            if (id == null)
            {
                return NotFound();
            }

            Assignment = await _context.TblPairings.FindAsync(id);

            if (Assignment != null)
            {
                _context.TblPairings.Remove(Assignment);
                await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
            }

            return RedirectToPage("./Index");
        }
    }
}
```

How can I change the RedirectToPage("./Index") to return the filtered page I was on when I post the record deletion?